# I need to run two functions onclick. I can't get them both to work even when nested together

Tags: javascript, validation, function, onclick, delay

The HTML is:

```
<input name="submit"
       type="submit"
       class="button"
       value="Click Here"
       tabindex="13"
       onclick="return ValidateForm();" />
```

The ValidateForm() function has all the usual form validating code.
The other function I can't get to run (except by itself it works fine..example

```
<input name="submit"
       type="submit"
       class="button"
       value="Click Here"
       tabindex="13"
       onclick="disDelay(this);" />
```

I tried putting them both after the onclick...example

```
<input name="submit"
       type="submit"
       class="button"
       value="Click Here"
       tabindex="13"
       onclick="return ValidateForm(); disDelay(this);" />
```

I also tried putting one the code in the same function with no success.

The function disDelay() is

```
function disDelay(obj){
    obj.setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
    setTimeout(function(){obj.removeAttribute('disabled')},10000);
}
```

It is to be used as a delay to keep the form from getting duplicate submissions from multiple clicks. The delay is at 10 seconds right now just for testing purposes.
I need the validation and delay to work together.

Comment: `element.onclick = function(){ function01(); function02(); };` don't put events on html :D

Comment: what is the behavior that you are observing?

Comment: It won't validate or delay when I incorrectly use both functions with onclick. When I use just one of the functions or the other it works fine but I need both.

Comment: If you did onsubmit() would multiple clicks even matter? If not then you could just leave out the delay (which would be pretty annoying in the first place for a user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Returning the value of the first function terminates the click handler. Essentially, this is what you're doing in your attempt to combine:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" 
       value="Click Here" tabindex="13" 
       onclick="return submit_Click(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit_Click(sender) {
        return ValidateForm(); 
        disDelay(sender); // !!! This call is unreachable !!!
    }
</script>
```

Here is one simple option to correct it:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" 
       value="Click Here" tabindex="13" 
       onclick="return submit_Click(this);" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit_Click(sender) {
        var r = ValidateForm(); 
        disDelay(sender); // It seems like you would only want to call this
                          // function if the form is validate, so there should
                          // probably be an if-statement surrounding it. However,
                          // I'll leave that up to you.
        return r;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You almost had it, just reverse the order of the function calls.

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Click Here" tabindex="13" onclick="disDelay(this); return ValidateForm(); " />
```

The return from ValidateForm is going to cause the rest of the code to be unreachable so it must be last.

Answer (score 0):

In your onclick string the disDelay(this) is not getting called because you return the response from ValidateForm(), so the second statement never executes.

If you absolutely must use the onclick attribute inside the html, try:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Click Here" tabindex="13" onclick="disDelay(); return ValidateForm();" />
```